# How to get a div to the bottom without content while still having a responsive design?

Tags: html, css

I have a left side nav with a main content area to the right of it.
Regardless of if the left side nav or the content area has any content i would like it to stretch down to the bottom of the container. Basically this is what im trying to do ([Stretching divs to bottom with a responsive grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979374/stretching-divs-to-bottom-with-a-responsive-grid)). The answer in this thread does not work for me since the content is not expanding the div properly when reaching the bottom of the container.

What i have tried is to use height on html,body and parent of the container including the container and while that gives the correct height the height isnt automatically re-calculated when the content reaches the bottom of the container (the div isnt moving further down and the content is overflowing). In this situation i have used the overflow property which works but i dont want a scrollbar in a div, i would like it to expand naturally further down the page.

I've created a very simple html and css example to show the problem:

HTML:

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .container {
      border: 2px solid red;
      width: 75%;
      height: 75%;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .content {
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .right-menu {
      border: 2px solid green;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 75%;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 15%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right-menu">
      <p>test</p>
      <p>this is a test</p>
      <p>this is a test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>this is a test</p>
      <p>this is a test</p>
      <p>this is a test</p>
      <p>this is another test</p>
      <p>this is a test</p>
      <p>this is a test</p>
      <p>this is another test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I currently have the overflow property specified above but i dont want the scrollbars and i do not want to hide any content as i would like the content to be visible for users. Basically a news feed going down the page which should automatically expand the div further down the page.

Does anyone have any good suggestions to this ? I see there are several threads and results for this but none seems to offer a good solutions or have a different problem than i have.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 75%;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.right-menu {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right-menu">
      <p>empty</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>empty</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I already have except from the border-box which only makes sure that you actually get the width you are specifying which is not the problem in this case. I usually use border-box but that is not a solution to the problem. If you add a lot of paragraphs in the content area you get the scrollbar because i have used the overflow property, but i want to remove the overflow property and still have the content flow properly when it reaches the bottom and still have the left nav have height it has in that example.

Comment: I also added a `height:100%` declaration to your `.right-menu`and `.content` divs, so they should always adjust, regardless of the container's `overflow` value.

Comment: When using your edited code and i remove the overflow property the content overflows so it doesnt adjust. Ive tried this several times as i also though that would work but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `flexbox` fixes this issue?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 70%;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
}
.right-menu {
  border: 2px solid green;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 15%;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-menu">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <p>this is a test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <p>this is another test</p>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <p>this is another test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to use flexbox, but as it does not have wide enough support yet i'm currently going the inline-block way for now so unfortunately im at this time locked out of flexbox. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easy fix...

Try

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 75%;
  min-height: 75%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Setting a min-height rather than a fixed height should allow the container to expand without scrollbars.

Comment: The content in the div with the content class is overflowing the yellow border. When the content hits the red border in the container it takes on the behaviour of an "overflow: hidden" property which looks wierd, so that does not work.

Comment: remove any overflow properties

Comment: Still the same except that the content now also overflows the red border. Weird that this doesnt work though but when setting any height property it looks like the auto-recalculating done by the browser just stops working (the browser seems to stop doing it) and all content just overflows. When the height isnt set the content flows like it should but then also only takes up as much space as it needs.